# Book recommendation: Homology theory in algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation

I am searching for a nice book to seriously learn the homology theory in algebraic topology with.
I am looking for a book that starts with (or gets quick to ) the axioms of homology theory.
I looked into several books before, which are either to advanced (Homotopical Theory by Fomenko and Fuchs, which I would love to study, but it is kind off weird), or do not exactly contain what I am searching for right now (An Introduction to Algebraic Topology by Rotman). Also some german textbooks on the topic, one of them seems fitting but assumes to much prior knowledge and advances therefore to quick (module theory, homological algebra, the needed category theory, difficult to read notation wise).

So is there a (pretty much) self contained textbook you would recommand on the topic?

Not everything needed for the book has to be covered of course, but I feel like many books on algebraic topology are hard to get into, and I am looking something to seriously get started in this field, and gets quick to applications and calculations of the developed theory.
So if you name a book and some other sources to get used to backround stuff, that would fit too.

Looking forward to your recommandations!
Thanks in advance.

Edit: When commenting, please do not just name a title, but also why you seem that this book fits, or what you liked about the book. This would help me.

Comment: Greenberg-Harper?

Comment: @SteveD I have found it online, and will look into it. Maybe you could elaborate more about this, then just naming the authors. That would be helpful. :)

Comment: Homology theory by James W Vick?

Comment: @NoelLundström I have looked into that book before (the preview in amazon) and it does not seem to fit into what I am searching for.

Comment: You can read the entire book [here](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4612-0881-5/page/n11/mode/2up). And from what I can see it does include everything you want? What is it missing?

Comment: @NoelLundström The book starts with singular homology. I am searching for a book that presents the axioms of homology theory at the beginning, tackeling every homology theory at once. So starts kind off with homological algebra, the necessary category theory and so on.